# Is it ok to use some button labels with verbs from the user's perspective and some with verbs from the system perspective in the same project?

Tags: labels, consistency

In some cases I have "See/view all" or "Go to comments", and then I have "Show details" or something like that.

I feel like the first set (See, View, Go to) is the system telling the user what to do, while "Show" is the user telling the system what action to perform - just from the linguistic point of view I guess.

But is it wrong considering UX consistency to use both throughout one project? If so, which way is preferable?

And is either one of those verbs ("See" or "View") better for some reason or are they equally good to use?

Comment: On ‘see’, ‘view’, ‘show’: there are (subtle) differences. Seeing is something the user does, so it is more an expression of what you want (a desire that the program can fulfill). Showing is something the program does, so it is more an expression of what you want the program to do (command). You might use these nuances to give the program a ‘personality’.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to have a verb for every action label, the interface can get overloaded. I would apply the user perspective with verbs for the top level actions e.g "See All", "Go to Comments". Within the sub action, I would drop the verb and just use "Details" or use an icon if possible.

Answer (score 0):

"View details"?

You should have a consistent taxonomy across project, especially with actions. 
That being said, it's not wrong to have some buttons trigger system actions and other user actions.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question of dialect and user preference. Some user testing and interviewing would probably reveal what most people would expect the label to read. In this case, I would ask the user to look at the prototype and tell them what the result of clicking the button would be without suggesting any of the labels I am on the fence about.

EX: If you click this button here, it will take you to a screen with more detailed information about this user. What would you expect the label on that button to be?

You would only need to ask 5-7 people before you began to see a pattern.